# McCleary Spectral Sequence: Is this a definition or a result of a theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

[image]

(McCleary's User Guide to Spectral Sequences pg 458)

I refer to the statement "We denote the $E^1$-term by $B_n^1\cong H_n(X;\mathbb{F}_p)$".

Is $B_n^1\cong H_n(X;\mathbb{F}_p)$ just a definition, or is it the result of some theorem? I am a bit confused since $B_n$ is sometimes used to denote boundary group, i.e. the image of the differential. Or does B just stand for Bockstein here (i.e. it is just a definition to be accepted)?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Perhaps its a typo? The ss asociated to an exact couple has by definition E^1 term given by the first bigraded group E in the triangle.

Comment: I don't think it is a typo, later the author calls the spectral sequence $\{B_*^r, d^r\}$. I am wondering is it just a simple case of replacing the traditional letter $E$ by letter $B$, or is there something deeper.

Comment: "B" for Bockstein, I guess. Actually, if you look at McCleary's proposition 10.4 you'll notice an interpretation as a boundary group, which are usually denoted by the letter "B".

Use of the letter B seems to be another of McCleary's quirks. No other author (including Browder in his original article) seem to adopt it.